# React router Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to implement React router for my app that looks like this

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

import Login from './Login';
import SignIn from './SignIn';
import Chat from './Chat';

require("../../view/style.less");

const app = document.getElementById('app');

ReactDOM.render((
   <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component ={Login} />
      <Route path="signin" component ={SignIn} />
      <Route path="chat" component ={Chat}  />
   </Router>
), app);
```

and when i look at my console it gives the error Unexpected token

here is the console error output. What is the problem?

```
 ReactDOM.render((
> 14 |    <Router history={browserHistory}>
     |    ^
  15 |       <Route path="/" component ={Login} />
  16 |       <Route path="signin" component ={SignIn} />
  17 |       <Route path="chat" component ={Chat}  />
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to enable JSX support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a story of parenthesis.

```
ReactDOM.render(
   <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component ={Login} />
      <Route path="signin" component ={SignIn} />
      <Route path="chat" component ={Chat}  />
   </Router>, app);
```